# Implement push notification firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the code from this page to get the token https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client but i am getting an error on this specific line `String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);` for msg_token_fmt saying can not resolve symbol. I have done all steps in this tutorial but i get this error.

This is the code

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
          if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
            return;
          }

          // Get new FCM registration token
          String token = task.getResult();

          // Log and toast
          String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
          Log.d(TAG, msg);
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code is just provided as an example.  If you don't intend to format the `token` string with a string resource from your app, then you don't need that line of code at all. Just do whatever you want with `token` after you receive it.  Typically you send it to your backend so that the token can be used to target this device with messages using the FCM send  API.

Comment: Oh i see. So through API i can use the token to send messages to a specific device?

Comment: That's what it's for.